# Improving User Class structure/design

Tags: php, object-oriented

I recently got into OOP, because I'm working on a big project and want to make sure my code is easy to maintain & scalable.

My question is - how could I go about properly structuring the following code? I have a feeling that there is a better way to do so. Perhaps you can give me some tips, as more experienced with OOP design.

```
  class User {
        public function getUser($user_id) {

        }
        public function getProfilePicture($user_id) {

        }
        public function isVerified($user_id) {

        }
        public function isVIP($user_id) {

        }
        public function getBadges($user_idt) {

        }
        public function getPhotos($user_id, $limit) {

        }
        public function isOnline($user_id) {

        }
        public function getNames($full_name) {
            $first_name = '';
            $last_name = '';
            return array('first_name' => $first_name, 'last_name' => $last_name);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As written, your class does not appear to actually represent a User. Rather, it looks like some sort of container for getting the properties of users.

1. You should add properties to contain the ID, names, etc. To ensure they are safe from being modified in an unacceptable way, make them as private and create methods that allow them to be modifier in controlled ways, if they need to be modifiable at all.
2. Second, the getter methods don't need to take a parameter to determine which User to query. Instead, they should return the value for the property contained within the object itself.

Additionally, the getters are arguably unnecessary and could be replaced with a single __get [magic method](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.set) if you're using an advanced enough version of PHP. I am not familiar enough with the language to say if that is the more idiomatic way.